# Chain imports work in Python 2 but fail in Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-import

I have a project with the following folder structure and file contents:

```
├── code
│   ├── my_lib
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── moduleA.py
│   │   └── moduleB.py
│   ├── scriptA.py
│   └── scriptB.py
```

**__init__.py**

```
#empty
```

**moduleA.py**

```
def funA():
    print("A")
```

**moduleB.py**

```
import moduleA

moduleA.funA()

def funB():
    print("B")
```

**scriptA.py**

```
from my_lib import moduleA

moduleA.funA()
```

**scriptB.py**

```
from my_lib import moduleB

moduleB.funB()
```

In Python 2.7, I can successfully run all four Python files. But with Python 3.5, I can't run `scriptB.py`, since it gives me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scriptB.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_lib import moduleB
  File "/home/marjan/Desktop/code/my_lib/moduleB.py", line 1, in <module>
    import moduleA
ImportError: No module named 'moduleA'
```

If I run `moduleB.py` (the one that is apparently causing the problems) on its own with Python 3, it runs without problems.

What principle is behind the different behaviour of chained imports in Python 2 vs Python 3, and how can I overcome the differences with minimal changes in the code or project structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

and then you just use the Python 3 way in both: your moduleB can use either

```
from mylib import moduleA
```

or

```
from . import moduleA  # Relative to directory of this module
```

but imports are never implicitly relative anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `from . import moduleA` in `moduleB.py` with `python3` for relative imports. Otherwise it is considered an absolute import.

Comment: I have got `Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import` by adding the dot and running scriptB.py again. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, you need to use `from . import moduleA` in `moduleB.py`.

Comment: Yes, not it works. Could you please correct your answer, so I can accept it without further confusion?

Comment: Done. But better accept RemcoGerlich's answer as it also contains the reference to `__future__`.